# Segmentation fault error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

`I am trying to write a program that reverses two strings, I though I had it done pretty well but when I run it, the program runs till line 26, then I get a segmentation fault error. The program compiles fine. I am wondering if there is a simple or obvious problem in my functions that I am not seeing, Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Reversing the characters in strings.

void reverse(string str);
void swap(char * first, char *last);

int main() {
    // declarations and initialization
    string str1;
    string str2;

    cout << "Please enter the first string of characters:\n";
    cin >> str1;

    cout << "Please enter the second string of characters:\n";
    cin >> str2;

    cout << "The strings before reversing are:" << endl;
    cout << str1 << " " << str2 << endl;

    // reverse str1
    reverse(str1);
    // reverse str2
    reverse(str2);

    // output
    cout << "The strings after reversing: " << endl;
    cout << str1 << " " << str2 << endl;

    return 0;
}

void reverse(string str) {
    int length = str.size();

    char *first = NULL;
    char *last = NULL;
    first = &str[0];
    last = &str[length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; first < last; i++) {
        swap(first, last);
        first++;
        last--;
    }
}

void swap(char *first, char *last) {
    char * temp;

    *temp = *first;
    *first = *last;
    *last = *temp;
}
```

Comment: After where it outputs "The strings before reversing are"...

Comment: Just so you know, you're passing the `string` by value into `reverse` so it won't actually reverse the strings.

Comment: so I do need to treat the strings as non array variables?

Comment: You should pass the strings by reference, and also don't mess with the string's memory directly. Use the `[]` operator instead of making pointers to the string's memory and using those.

Comment: Agree with Seth - and you also dont need char * - just a char to hold and swap the letters around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `swap` function, you are assigning a value to `*temp` when `temp` is not pointing to anything (it's uninitialized). Thus, your segmentation fault.

You want this:

```
void swap(char* first, char* last)
{
    char temp = *first;
    *first = *last;
    *last = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know where line 26 is, but

```
char * temp;
*temp = ...
```

is not valid.  `temp` should be pointed at a `char`, or (better yet) rewrite the function to where `temp` *is* a `char`.

Seth Carnegie observes that you'll have to pass the `string`s by reference if you want to modify the originals.

```
void reverse(string& str) { //pass by reference, so origional is modified
```

Comment: I see how that would work better but it is for homework and I have to use strings, no reference values...

Comment: @user1050853 it is still very much a string, you're just passing it by reference, so that whatever changes are made inside the function affect the value outside the function. If you don't pass it by reference, the function will reverse its local copy of the string, and when it returns, the reversed one will be lost.

Comment: @user1050853 If you absolutely refuse to pass by reference then you should at least return a copy of the reversed string...

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the strings by value, which means only a local copy of the string will be reversed in the `reverse` function. You should pass them by reference.

Also, don't alter the string's memory directly. Use `operator[]` like this:

```
for (size_t beg = 0, size_t end = str.size() - 1; beg < end; ++beg, --end)
    str[beg] = str[end];
```

So all together:

```
void reverse(string& str); // prototype

....

void reverse(string& str) { // note the & which is pass by reference
    int length = str.size();

    for (size_t beg = 0, size_t end = str.size() - 1; beg < end; ++beg, --end)
        str[beg] = str[end];
}
```

And as stated by Mooing Duck, the place you're probably crashing from is dereferencing a pointer which has a garbage value here:

```
char * temp;
*temp = ...
```

You're trying to assign some random memory a value, which is probably segfaulting you.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are valid in regards to the segfault cause.

I just think you may be interested in knowing that you can reverse a string easily using `std::string`'s `reverse_iterator`:

```
std::string reverse(std::string str) {
    std::string out;
    for (std::string::reverse_iterator it = str.rbegin(); it != str.rend(); it++) {
        out += *it;
    }
    return out;
}
```

So, calling:

```
reverse("foo");
```

...will return `oof`.

Comment: Thanks, This project is for homework or else I would definitly use that

Comment: Just because you don't care doesn't mean no one does, and this isn't a micro optimisation. Taking and returning strings by value and building strings one character at a time via concatenation will not be good for large strings. And even so, I wasn't saying this should never be used, I was just trying to provide a _caveat emptor_ for readers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Again, others have pointed out the what the problem is and would like to show you this:

```
void reverse(std::string & str) {     
 for (int i = 0, last = str.size() - 1, lim = str.size() / 2 ; i < lim;) {
  std::swap(str[i++], str[last--]);
 } 
}
```

I have not tested it thoroughly though.